# Defining new accents in LaTeX

Tags: macros, accents

The documents that I type include lots of references to complex numbers and their complex conjugates, such as `$j, \overline{j}$`.

I would find it lots easier to be able to type something as `\*j` to denote `\overline{j}`. Then `\*` would work very much like an accent, applying only to the next symbol if no curly braces are present.

However, using `\renewcommand{\*}[1]{\overline{#1}}` doesn't yield satisfactory results at all: `(x^\*j)` yields [image].

Ideas?

Comment: How would you like `$x^\*j$` to render?

Comment: @CFP: Shouldn't it be `$(x^{\*j})$` ?; otherwise, using `$x^\*j$` will produce an error.

Comment: @Caramdir: I'd like it to render as `$x^{\overline{j}}$.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Yes, but I was searching for a quicker way to write it...

Comment: @CFP: You're writing "`(x^\*j)` renders as $(x^{\overline{j})}$." Do you actually mean "I _would like_ `(x^\*j)` to render as $(x^{\overline{j})}$"? (And probably better "yield" instead of "render as"?) If yes, then it would be great if you can edit your question accordingly; at the moment it's somewhat confusing. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Hendrik: I've fixed my question. Thanks for your comment, such remarks are highly appreciated.

Comment: I meant that my current construct yields an x followed by two characters in the exponent, `j` and `)`. When I write `(x + x^\*j - 1)`, I want it to only put the `j` in exponent. Your solution works perfectly, though.

Comment: @CFP: I'm a little bit surprised by the behaviour you describe. Doesn't it also throw an error like "missing brace inserted"?

Comment: @Bruno: I was surprised, too, but I think the point is: Yes, it does throw an error, but if you just hit "q" and are happy with it, then you get the output CFP is describing.

Comment: @CFP: I think now I got why we didn't understand you at first. When you used `$...$`, then you didn't mean TeX code but the output you got, correct? I replaced your second `$...$` with the corresponding image; I think this way your question is much clearer. OK? When we read "$(x^{\overline{j})}$" here, we always think of the TeX code and not of the output. (Moreover, I didn't even realize that the `)` was _inside_ the outer `{}`.)

Comment: @Hendrik, @CFP: what happens is that TeX inserts `{` before `\overline`, trying to recover from `^\overline`, and then inserts `}` before the closing dollar, hence the weird output.

Comment: @Hendrik: Exactly, sorry for not including images!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the specific application that you mention, you can simply double the braces in the definition of `\*`. Namely,

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\*}[1]{{\overline{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
(x^\*j)
\]
\end{document}
```

The default behaviour of `^` is that it expands what follows until it cannot anymore. Once that happens, `^` will grab whatever is the next "token", and put it as an exponent. With your definition of `\*`, the expansion transforms `(x^\*j)` into `(x^\overline{j})`. Then TeX cannot expand `\overline` more, so it puts `\overline` as the exponent of `x`. But that's not going to work, because `\overline` takes an argument.

With the extra set of braces, the same expression expands to `(x^{\overline{j}})`, and the whole expression is in braces.

I would advise against that solution though, and instead type `$(x^{\*j})$`, keeping your previous definition. You should not rely on the fact that `^` expands its argument before grabbing it: some packages change that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanations. I'll follow your advice, and write it cleanly =) Thanks!